# Why is there a mysql tag and a mysql-query tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: One is a tag for MySQL. The other is for the `mysql-query` PHP function.

Comment: @26years of Welbog. That makes sense. Put it in as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.